# IDEA: Do you think this would stop emails from being scraped?

Tags: email, email-spam

I put a span class in the middle of the email, like so:

`example<span class='scrape'>DELETE-THIS</span>@website.com`

I set the scrape class to `position:fixed` and `right:200%`. The email address appears normally on the page. Then I added some Javascript that deletes the span on mousedown, since bots can't click.

What do people think? Would this stop an email from being scraped?

Answer (score 0):

Most bots target a links with a regular expression looking for an @ symbol and sufficiently complex ones are capable of parsing the content of a document as well as its html. While this might hinder the ability of a bot to parse it via html it does not hinder the plain text methods.

A better defense is to store the email address as a Data-Attribute and then use an event to transform it from the Data-Attribute into a MailTo: link or however you wish to use it. This will cause the page to be loaded asynchronously which will prevent most batch style bots.

Comment: Most times I use AJAX contact forms with a click event, so it's not a problem. But this client wanted to actually display the email address.

When, exactly, does the text get parsed? There's a ~1s preloader on the site, so if I added the email address after 500ms or so, would that avoid most bots? Or do they parse when the page is 100% loaded?

Comment: Depends on the bot, but after some heuristic analysis of my own sites I've found that 83% of bots don't stick around after the page is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "email address munging". It would be cleaner to use display:none though.

It works on some bots but not all.